# Prevent windows service from starting

Tags: c#, windows-services

**Situation**

There's a windows service given and I want to implement something like an auto-update feature. For this case I call another executable file which handles the update process.

```
public partial class Main : ServiceBase
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TryUpdate();

        /* Some Extra Code */
    }


    private void TryUpdate()
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"UpdateCheck.exe";
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        if (proc.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            Process proc2 = new Process();
            proc2.StartInfo.FileName = @"UpdateCheck.exe";
            proc2.StartInfo.Arguments = "Update";
            proc2.Start();

            /* Here is where I want the application to quit! */
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        /* Some Extra Code */

        base.OnStart(args);
    }
}
```

When I call the TryUpdate-Function, it starts another process which determines if there's an update available or not. If there is one, I call the process again with the parameter to update the service (it basically just waits for a few seconds so that the service can shut down and then uninstalls and installs the service using an installshield setup).

Obviously it is not the smartest solution. The problem I am facing now though is the following:

When I throw an Exception to stop the service from starting (I guess?) the application crashes and tells me the service did not respond in a timely fashion (Error 1053).

**Actual Question**

How do I cancel a windows service properly at this state?

Comment: If you derive from ServiceBase you can call this.Stop() . E.g. http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/

Comment: Wow, it's a shame I did not try this. Works like a charm, thank you!